# I can't load layer into qthread object in QGIS

Tags: python, pyqgis, layers

Below, I show you an extract of the code to load a layer using threads, following the instructions shown here: [Snorfalorpagus](https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2013/12/07/multithreading-in-qgis-python-plugins/)
But the layer does not load, or it loads but it is not shown, and the truth is that I have no idea why this happens

```
class Worker(QtCore.QObject):

def __init__(self):
    QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    path = "C:\Users\user\Documents"
    layer = QgsVectorLayer(path, "Layer.shp", "ogr")
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer) 
    ...
```

---

**Edit copied in by mod from answer response:**

1. Yes, a cut/paste error was here, but don't in PY file,sorry.
2. yes, I tested that layer is valid with method 'layer.isValid()' and return True, for this, I supposse that layer is loaded, but I don't know, why it Don't show in Layer Panel.
3. and the MainClass with call and run the worked class is..

   class MainClass:
   """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

   ```
   def __init__(self, iface):
   ...
   def run(self):
       """Run method that performs all the real work"""

       # show the dialog
       self.dlg.show()
       # Run the dialog event loop
       result = self.dlg.exec_()
       # See if OK was pressed
       if result:
           # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
           # substitute with your code.

           # start the Worker in a new thread
           thread = QtCore.QThread(self.iface)
           worker = Worker(arg)           
           worker.moveToThread(thread)
           worker.finished.connect(self.workerFinished)
           worker.error.connect(self.workerError)
           worker.progress.connect(progressBar.setValue)
           thread.started.connect(worker.run)
           thread.start()
           self.thread = thread
           self.worker = worker
   ```

And Sorry for my english.

Comment: 1. Your python indentation is wrong, is that just a cut/paste here problem? 2. Have you tested that `layer` is valid after the call to `QgsVectorLayer`? 3. How have you called this class and its run method?